# checking for existence of existing File System

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a prd version of my terraform code to azure.
In this code, I've got 3 data lakes, and their filesystem.
During my dev deployment, this worked, but now, with another sub, spn, storage account, it doesn't, i'm getting following error:

```
checking for existence of existing File System "bronze" (Account "xxx"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
```

I even made the spn owner of the sub, but no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the  **`Storage Blob Data Owner`** role is assigned to you in order to to create or update the filesystem.

Particulary check the role is given in the  current subscription credentials

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "storage blob data owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
resource "time_sleep" "role_assignment_sleep" {
  create_duration = "60s"

  triggers = {
    role_assignment = azurerm_role_assignment.role_assignment.id
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "kaexamplestorageacc"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = "true"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "kadlsexample"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  properties = {
    hello = "aGVsbG8="
  }
depends_on         = [time_sleep.role_assignment_sleep]

}
```

Note:
Give time for role to reflest by using time sleep.

[image]